# R: Round a data frame with a specific formula across all columns with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rounding, across

I would like to use the following formula to round my whole data frame in R:

```
format(round(Df$`p-value`, digits=2), nsmall = 2)
```

Now, the code above is only for one column (just to show you).

I know dplyr is easy to use when I want to use the formula for my whole data frame as there is the  `across()` function.
I tried the following:

```
Df %>%
mutate(across(format(round(digits=2), nsmall = 2)))
```

However, I get an error, saying that "argument "x" is missing, with no default".
I assume I need to make a small adjustment to the code but I couldn't figure out what I need to adjust? Could someone help me here please?

Thank you.

Comment: try mutate(across(~format(round(digits=2), nsmall = 2)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot argument x in it. R is completely right.
You need to get the dataframe (argument x) in the function which you want to convert. In this case a "." represents the dataframe, because its dplyr. You mutate(across) was not working for me, so I decided to use mutate_all, which does the job perfectly.

```
A %>%    mutate_all(~format(round(., digits=1), nsmall = 2))
```

Comment: Another way to write it would be  `mtcars %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ format(round(.x, digits=2), nsmall = 2)))`     The x is the element that the function across will use, in this case everything

Comment: @pbraeutigm great, thank you very much! This works perfectly. I just had to adjust digits=2 but that was ok.

Comment: @r2evans if I use "==" I get TRUE / FALSE, if I use "=" I get the result.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it. You need to specify the .fns argument by name or the formula will be matched by position to the first argument of across, .cols.

> DF %>%
> mutate(
> across(
> .fns = ~ format(round(.x, digits = 2), nsmall = 2)
> )

Comment: Thank you for your response! The thing is I also need nsmall since I have values smaller than zero and otherwise when I round these numbers I just get 0 instead of e.g., 0.01. But the answers above worked for me.

Comment: My apologies! Was on my phone and misread your question. Have updated solution above

Answer (score 0):

First I create some random data:

```
Df <- data.frame(v1 = c(1.21,3.21,2.2,1.11),
                 v2 = c(1.333, 2.22,1.1111,2.1))
```

You can use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
Df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(~format(round(digits=2), nsmall = 2))))
```

Output:

```
    v1     v2
1 1.21 1.3330
2 3.21 2.2200
3 2.20 1.1111
4 1.11 2.1000
```